# TFS 2018 - Change Collection Name

Tags: tfs

I've been researching about the proper way to change a Collection name in TFS 2018.

I've found this URL:
http://accentient.com/blog/rename-a-tfs-project-collection/

In this document it is mentioned that we should change the database name to match the name of the Collection, at the time I attach the collection in the Administration Console of TFS 2018.

Is it really necessary to change the collection name in the database or is it enough to change the Collection name in the Administration Console (leaving the DB name as it is)?

Comment: It's not necessary, but it's a good idea to keep everything consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I`ve checked on my test environment:

[image]

It works without the database name changing:

[image]

**Don`t forget to backup your DB.**